# Interactable script allows "Hand follow transform", defaults to transform of the attached object, ignoring offset

Tags: unity-game-engine, steamvr

We are building a 3D VR billiard, and we are struggling with the Cue-Stick.

We try to use the steamVR Interactable scripts as much as we can.

I attach the Cue stick to the hand with

```cs
hand.AttachObject(gameObject, GrabTypes.Grip, Hand.AttachmentFlags.VelocityMovement, Pivot.transform);
```

The Offset (`Pivot.transform` is important here because we want to attach to the object at the correct position (which is determined on runtime, depending on where the user puts his hand when grabbing).
Because the Cue stick is moved using velocities and not via parenting, the grab position will not always be on the stick (stick has drag, collision, etc). This is quite immersion breaking. 
To compensate for this problem the Intractable script has a boolean for `Hand Follow Transform` which would be perfect for fixing this. 
Sadly the Hand now jumps to the midpoint (origin) of the Cue, even though we grabbed it somewhere completely different. It still behaves like it should, but visually its very confusing.

SteamVR Intractable supports the offset when attaching, but it forgets about that offset when positioning the hand.

Is there something I am missing? 
Or is this just not a thing?

I read though the script codes multiple times and it seams like the offset is not available in the scope where the hand is placed. So there seams no way this can work.

How can I solve this problem?

I tried falling back to just parenting to the hand, but this makes physics interactions between Cue and balls funky. 
I also read through most of the `Interactable` and the `Hand` script to understand whats going on, other that valves naming conventions hurting me a bit I was not successful in finding a way. 
I am quite overwhelmed by it though and I can see a good chance that I am missing something.

What probably is possible though, is to set the Hand attachment point to the correct place on the Cue, but this transform is placed in the `RightHand` (and left) prefab, it seams like a really bad idea to change this transform every frame, or parenting it to the Cue gameobject.

Is there a better way?